# [SOLVED]Syncronize threads from different processes to take effect in a specific order Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I was given a processes hierrarchy with 5 threads for processes 3 and 5. I have to syncronize these threads by using System V,POSIX semaphores or POSIX locks. I think it's mostly my bad undnerstanding of how the value for a semaphore works and no knowledge of how shared semaphores work. I have to make sure that thread 3.4 ends before thread 5.1 starts, and 3.5 starts after 5.1 ends.
Every thread and process has this INFO(BEGIN/END,processNO,threadNO) which need to be added when a thread starts or ends. 
ex:

```
INFO(BEGIN,3,4); //This means process 3, thread 4 stars
printf("%d",4);
INFO(END,3,4);
```

```
void* threadFunctionQ5(void* params){
    structura5* param=(structura5*)params;
    sem_wait(param->semaphmain);
    if(param->value==5){
        sem_wait(param->semaph1);
    }
    info(BEGIN,3,param->value);
    info(END,3,param->value);
    if(param->value==4){
        sem_post(param->semaph5);
    }
    sem_post(param->semaphmain);
    return NULL;
}


void* threadFunctionQ3(void* params){
    structura3* param=(structura3*)params;
    sem_wait(param->semaphmain);
        if(param->value==1){
            sem_wait(param->semaph5q5);
        }
        info(BEGIN,5,param->value);

        info(END,5,param->value);
        if(param->value==1){
            sem_post(param->semaph1q5);
        }
    sem_post(param->semaphmain);
    return NULL;
}
void question5(){
    pthread_t threads[5];
    structura5 params[5];
    sem_t semaphmain;
    sem_t* semaph1q5=sem_open("Semafor1",O_CREAT,0644,0);
    sem_t* semaph5q5=sem_open("Semafor5",O_CREAT,0644,0);
    if(sem_init(&semaphmain,0,1)!=0){
        printf("Error in initializing in q5");
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        params[i].semaphmain=&semaphmain;
        params[i].semaph1=semaph1q5;
        params[i].semaph5=semaph5q5;
        params[i].value=i+1;
        pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,threadFunctionQ5,&params[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }
    sem_unlink("Semafor1");
    sem_unlink("Semafor5");
}
void question3(){
    pthread_t threads[5];
    structura3 params[5];
    sem_t semafor2,semafor4,semaforCerinta;
    sem_t* semaph1q5=sem_open("Semafor1",O_CREAT,0644,0);
    sem_t* semaph5q5=sem_open("Semafor5",O_CREAT,0644,0);
    if(sem_init(&semafor2,0,0)!=0 || sem_init(&semafor4,0,0)!=0 || sem_init(&semaforCerinta,0,3)){
        printf("Error in initializing semaphores in q3");
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        params[i].semaphmain=&semaforCerinta;
        params[i].semaph1q5=semaph1q5;
        params[i].semaph5q5=semaph5q5;
        params[i].semafor2=&semafor2;
        params[i].semafor4=&semafor4;
        params[i].value=i+1;
        pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,threadFunctionQ3,&params[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }
    sem_unlink("Semafor1");
    sem_unlink("Semafor5");
    sem_destroy(&semafor2);
    sem_destroy(&semafor4); 
}
```

Those 2 called questionX() are functions called inside the x process declaration; The problem is that I don't get the wanted behaviour,my waits and posts don't do anything, but they get called since if I delete a sem_wait or a sem_post I get an infinite waiting state.I can't give the exact output since I have a tester with 5 tests that should work, but those 3 threads should follow the above ideea. Semafor4 and semafor2 were from a previous task where I had to work inside the same process so I guess they don't affect it in any way.

The strucs

```
typedef struct{
    int value;
    sem_t* semaphmain;
    sem_t* semaph5;
    sem_t* semaph1;
}structura5;


typedef struct{
    int value;
    sem_t* semafor2;
    sem_t* semafor4;
    sem_t* semaphmain;
    sem_t* semaph1q5;
    sem_t* semaph5q5;
}structura3;
```

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst other problems, it is missing the `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) use an appropriate space: inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons. around C operators  2) please consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. (don't use tabs for indenting as every editor has its' own tab mapping   3) at least supply a prototype for every function that is referenced, even if the body of the function is not posted.

Comment: Please post the definition of `BEGIN`, `END`, and `INFO()`

Comment: the function: `fork()` returns three kinds of results:  1) >0 means parent process 2) ==0 means child process 3) <0 means an error occurred.   All three conditions need to be checked after every call to `fork()`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  2) separate functions by 2 or 3 (be consistent) blank lines

Comment: regarding statements like: `printf("Eroare threaduri shared");`   Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  When the error is from a C library function should also output, to stderr, the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` is made to output both your error message and the text reason for the error to `stderr`.  Note:  the pthread functions do not set `errno` so need to use a statement similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "pthread_create failed\n" );`

Comment: since the semaphores are not used for counting, strongly suggest using `pthread_mutex_t`, pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` for synchronization.   You may also find: `
    `pthread_cond_init()`
    `pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;`
    `pthread_cond_destroy()`
    `pthread_cond_wait()`
    `pthread_cond_signal()`  to be very helpful for handling thread scynchronization

Comment: It was a mistake in the conditions, but I do appreciate all the comments. I will use perror from now on and will try to learn mutex locks. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3629249 the BEGIN,END and INFO() were given to me by the teacher in a seperate program

Comment: regarding: BEGIN, END, and INFO()   It matters not as to where you obtained them.  Your posted code is using them, Therefore, for us to duplicate your problem, we need to know them.  So their definitions needs to be in your posted code.